# Iterate ArrayList With Integers

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList of Nodes called secondNodeArray. I then have a Queue with Nodes in it called queueNode and a second ArrayList of Nodes called FirstNodeArray.

I am trying to make some loops that check each node within the secondNodeArray and see if the queueNode or FirstNodeArray contains it

I know how to set up the initial loop but when it comes to nesting them out I am getting a little lost

```
for(int i=0; i<secondNodeArray.length(); i++){
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop each array inside the secondNodeArray separately and when found, set the flag to true. To shorten the processtime break the loop after success.

```
boolean inFirstNode = false;
boolean inQueueNode = false;
for(int i=0; i < secondNodeArray.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j < firstNodeArray.size(); i++){
        // Pseudocode
        if firstNodeArray[j] equals secondNodeArray[i] {
            inFirstNode = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int j=0; j < queueNode.size(); i++){
        // Pseudocode
        if queueNode[j] equals secondNodeArray[i] {
            inQueueNode = true;
            break;
    }
    }
}
```

You also should think about, if array is the correct datastructure.

Comment: `ArrayList`, the collection that OP is working with, does not have a `length()` method.

Comment: @JacobG. I got it all figured out it was just a loop structure I couldn't get. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @KaitlynWheeler this loop structure is just as slow, if not slower, than your previous solution that used `List#contains`.

Comment: As @JacobG.mentioned in the solution... determine if using HashSet speeds up your code.

Answer (score 3):

> I cannot use .contains() as it significantly slows down the run time of my program for some reason so I believe loops are the next best way to do it

`List#contains` uses a loop internally, so nothing will change with your proposed solution.

Your goal **should** be to reduce the time complexity of the search instead, as `List#contains` requires linear time, `O(n)`, whereas other collections (such as a `HashSet`) require constant time, `O(1)`.

To determine if using a `HashSet` (instead of an `ArrayList`) is a viable solution, you'll need to determine if you can sacrifice storing duplicate elements in your collection, however you have not provided enough context in your question for anyone to make that decision.

If duplicate elements **are** required in the collection, then there's an alternative of storing them in your `ArrayList` in a sorted order (assuming your node objects are comparable); doing so will allow you to perform a binary search, which will still be much quicker than a linear search when working with a large collection.